# Best practice for POST data in TYPO3/Extbase (REST API)

Tags: php, typo3, extbase

I'm building a extension in extbase (TYPO3 7.6, update to 8 LTS as soon as possible) where one feature is like a REST API.
Someone needs to create a new object / database entry from a smartphone app. The app would just send a post request with the Data to a URL, and checks the responding status code.

**The first thing: How to access the Post data?**
If I build a fluid form, I will get a object as parameter to my action, which is in the most cases already validated. But how about manual Post requests?
I know that I can get a single parameter via `$this->request->getArguments()`
But is that the best way?
**The second thing: How to authenticate the User?**
Normally I would use the login form from TYPO3, and get the user ID from `$GLOBALS['TSFE']`
But in my API, I don't have a session or login Form. Username and Password can only be provided on each POST request. How can or should I authenticate the User?
I don't want to re-invent the wheel if Extbase / TYPO3 has already a function for that.

Answer (score 1):

For the authentication you could go for a HTTP basic authentication where you base64 encode the username and password and send it via header with your request:

```
Authorization: Basic QWxhZGRpbjpvcGVuIHNlc2FtZQ==
```

In TYPO3 you could register a custom AuthenticationProvider that authenticates a frontend user based on that. You should use HTTPS for this (well, you should use HTTPS in any case).

As for the creation of a record based on POST data, extbase already respects POST data, so if you just provide the data as it would be submitted by a form that uses the post method, everything should work.

It is getting more tricky if you need to cover PUT and DELETE requests as well.